# Vacuum vessel at 10mbar with a diaphragm pump: do I need a venting valve?

Tags: vacuum, vacuum-pumps

I'm working my way through learning vacuum technology.

I have a 10l vessel which I want to evacuate to < 10mbar. I'll use [this diaphragm pump](https://www.pfeiffer-vacuum.com/en/products/diaphragm-pumps/mvp-006/?detailPdoId=4223).

Do I need to add a (manual) venting valve to the system, or will switching off the pump do the job?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a vacuum expert, but if you look at the technical data for your pump, you'll find this "Leak rate 6x10-3 Pa m³/s". I take this to mean that your 10 liter = 0.01 m$^3$ vessel will leak at a rate of 0.6 Pa/s.  That's pretty slow.  You'll want a manual venting value.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely want more than just a vent valve - to avoid contamination of a vacuum chamber, typically you re-pressurize with an inert gas like nitrogen to avoid sucking condensates and water vapor into the chamber. Every time you add some condensate to the chamber, they'll need to desorb - which is an extremely slow process compared to pumpdown.